# How to get the sentiment score of each word in sentence based sentiment classification using RNN/LSTM?

Tags: nlp, deep-learning, theano, keras

If I use RNN/LSTM for sentence-based sentiment analysis, how do I get the sentiment/distribution/confidence of each word?  I just read one article shown here: [Neural network that remembers](http://spectrum.ieee.org/computing/software/the-neural-network-that-remembers)

It includes one picture as below, how to get the likelihood of each character what if I only do the classification in sentence-level? I know how to use LSTM for sentence classification, but we only use the last hidden representation for classification, so how to get the likelihood of each character/word?

An practical example showing what is the input and output would be great!

[image]

Comment: you can feed LSTM one character at a time and performs classification at each time-step, this is only for logging purposes (and you may get something similar to this graph) but since the training data will most probably have labeled per sentence you only have to propagate errors at last time step (i.e use hidden representation at last time-step for final (actual) classification). This is fairly straight forward to do in Theano, as users themselves have to define individual components, I am not sure how can you do it in Keras (as I don't use it).

Comment: Thanks for your comment@uyaseen, I will think more about it.